# How do i unfreeze my iPhone 7 when it is stuck on the lock screen? What do I do?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone screen is completely frozen. I've pressed the power button by itself to turn my phone off but when it cut back on it was still frozen, so I have no way into my phone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-207128/), you press and hold the Power Button. While holding the Power button down, press and hold the volume down button. Continue holding these buttons until you see the Apple Logo after the power comes back on.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: i've tried this like 30 times and still doesn't work..

Comment: Do you have a mac computer?  There is another way but it requires you to connect to a Mac.

Comment: You stated in your question that you just pressed the power button only. In that case you haven't tried my answer. Its more than just pressing the power button.